# Parsing webpage with java into excel and using hyperlinks

Tags: java, excel, hyperlink, apache-poi, jsoup

I'm very new to Apache POI and Jsoup and I'm extremely confused. I'm trying to parse this file into excel:

[image]

I want each column to be a column in my excel spreadsheet. The entries in the "Data File", "Stata Data File" and "Dictionary" columns are hyperlinks that download a .zip file when pressed. I know Apache POI can create hyperlinks, but can it parse these existing hyperlinks into excel as well? Also, this data is from a webpage, not a specific file, so is this even possible with java?

Could someone point me in the right direction? If this project is possible, would it be better to use POI or Jsoup? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you should split this task into two steps, and you are going to need both Jsoup and POI since they solve different problems.

1. Grab web page and parse (Jsoup)
2. Write parsed results into an excel spreadsheet (POI)

1) You can use Jsoup to get and parse the web page, the [Jsoup Cookbook](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url) has many simple examples how you can do this. You could e.g.:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get(); // Grab page
Element table = doc.getElementById("my-table"); // Get table with id "my-table"
```

By using selectors you could read the data you need and write it to POJOs or anywhere you like really.

2) Once you have the data you need you can create an excel spreadsheet using POI.

The Busy Developer guides shows [how to write to an excel sheet](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CreateCells) and how to create [hyperlinks](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Hyperlinks).

The gist of creating hyperlinks is:

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Test sheet");

Cell cell = sheet.createRow(0).createCell((short)0);
cell.setCellValue("URL Link"); // Text that will be shown, e.g. AL2015

Hyperlink link = createHelper.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_URL);
link.setAddress("http://poi.apache.org/"); // Set actual hyperlink URL
cell.setHyperlink(link); // Add hyperlink to cell
```